# How you do you get fields from an IndexReader now that TermEnum doesnt exist in Lucene 4.1?

Tags: java, lucene

Whats the equivalent of this 3.6 code in Lucene 4.1:

```
IndexReader ir = IndexReader.open(dir);
TermEnum termEnum = ir.terms(t);
```

that is use in many of my testcases

I've checked the migration guide which says

```
TermEnum termsEnum = ...;
while(termsEnum.next()) {
  Term t = termsEnum.term();
  System.out.println("field=" + t.field() + "; text=" + t.text());
}

Do this:

for(String field : fields) {
    Terms terms = fields.terms(field);
    TermsEnum termsEnum = terms.iterator(null);
    BytesRef text;
    while((text = termsEnum.next()) != null) {
      System.out.println("field=" + field + "; text=" + text.utf8ToString());
  }
}
```

but but where does field come from, how do i get fields from my IndexReader

Comment: Nevermind found it MultiFields.getFields(ir);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
MultiFields.getFields(ir)
```

instead